# PHPUnit assertNull() test fails

Tags: php, phpunit, assertions

I am sure the array I test is null. Even doing `var_dump(array)` prints `array(0) {
}`.

But the test `$this->assertNull($array);` fails.
On the contrary when I test below code it enters `if` condition :

```
if ($array == null) {
    echo "Entered";
} else {
    echo "Not Entered";
}
```

I don't understand why this is so. Please explain me if any one know the reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`array(0) { }` is an empty array.

`null` would the lack of an array at all.

They're not the same thing.

The problem with == is that it tries to type juggle the values to match them. An empty array is "falsy", as is `null`.

If you want to see the difference, use `===` instead, which does not type juggle and also compares type;

```
$array1 = null;
$array2 = array();
if ($array1 == null) echo '1';     // $array1 is "similar to" null.
if ($array1 === null) echo '2';    // $array1 is null
if ($array2 == null) echo '3';     // $array2 is "similar to" null
if ($array2 === null) echo '4';    // $array2 is null

>>> 123
```

[More on the comparison operators here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).

Comment: Then why `if ($array == null)` is satisfied.

Comment: Because it is typecasting the values to compare them. Try using `$array === null`. And have a look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php to see what PHP compares.

Comment: Thanks for example and explanation.